# Where does sendmail get its user authentication information?

Tags: centos, smtp, sendmail

I set up a new remote CentOS email server using sendmail and dovecot.  I am able to receive mail into mailboxes but can not use SMTP to send.

Trying to login by hand using

```
# telnet mail.steelydev.com 25
Trying 100.100.100.100...
Connected to mail.domain.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 domain.com ESMTP
ehlo www.domain2.com
250-domain.com Hello pool-100-100-198-241.man.east.myfairpoint.net [100.100.198.241], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE 15000000
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH GSSAPI CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN
250-STARTTLS
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
auth plain AGdlb2ZmAEpCUXhCOXJ6YnkxXX==
535 5.7.0 authentication failed
```

It's as if none of my users exist.  **So where is sendmail getting the passwords from?**

**EDIT 1**

Taking the suggestion that my ISP is actually giving me their SMTP I altered my sendmail.mc to remove DIGEST-MD5 as you can see in the updated telnet session above.

Also, I appreciate the other observations, but I'm falling back to canonical methods to debug the server.  I thought starting with plain auth on 25 would be the easiest.

roundcube webmail running thru apache can send and receive with no problem. I know it's using dovecot and /etc/dovecot/users for authentication.

Installed software not counting www stuff apache, roundcube ...

```
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804
yum install sendmail sendmail-cf m4
yum install telnet
yum install mail
yum install mailx
yum install netstat
yum install apt-get
yum install net-tools
yum install dovecot squirrelmail
yum -y install epel-release
yum -y install --disablerepo-epel*
yum install httpd php php-common php-json php-xml php-mbstring php-imap php-pear-DB php-mysql mysql mariadb-server
yum install httpd mod_ssl
yum install dig
yum install bind-utils
yum install epel-release
yum install httpd mod_ssl python-certbot-apache
yum install cyrus-sasl-gssapi
yum install cyrus-sasl-md5
yum install cyrus-sasl
yum install cyrus-plain
yum install cyrus-sasl-plain
yum install cyrus-sasl-devel
yum install httpd mod_ssl
```

And the the sendmail.mc file with unused lines removed:

```
divert(-1)dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail-cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`setup for linux')dnl
OSTYPE(`linux')dnl
define(`confDEF_USER_ID', ``8:12'')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `1m')dnl
define(`confTRY_NULL_MX_LIST', `True')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`PROCMAIL_MAILER_PATH', `/usr/bin/procmail')dnl
define(`ALIAS_FILE', `/etc/aliases')dnl
define(`STATUS_FILE', `/var/log/mail/statistics')dnl
define(`UUCP_MAILER_MAX', `2000000')dnl
define(`confUSERDB_SPEC', `/etc/mail/userdb.db')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,novrfy,noexpn,restrictqrun')dnl
define(`confAUTH_OPTIONS', `A')dnl
TRUST_AUTH_MECH(`EXTERNAL DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confAUTH_MECHANISMS', `EXTERNAL GSSAPI  CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN')dnl
define(`confTO_IDENT', `0')dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa', `dnl')dnl
FEATURE(`smrsh', `/usr/sbin/smrsh')dnl
FEATURE(`mailertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/mailertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(`virtusertable', `hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable.db')dnl
FEATURE(redirect)dnl
FEATURE(always_add_domain)dnl
FEATURE(use_cw_file)dnl
FEATURE(use_ct_file)dnl
FEATURE(local_procmail, `', `procmail -t -Y -a $h -d $u')dnl
FEATURE(`access_db', `hash -T<TMPF> -o /etc/mail/access.db')dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
EXPOSED_USER(`root')dnl
FEATURE(`accept_unresolvable_domains')dnl
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`localhost.localdomain')dnl
define(`confCACERT_PATH', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com')dnl
define(`confCACERT', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/fullchain.pem')dnl
define(`confSERVER_CERT', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/fullchain.pem')dnl
define(`confSERVER_KEY', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/privkey.pem')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_CERT', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/fullchain.pem')dnl
define(`confCLIENT_KEY', `/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/privkey.pem')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet, Port=465, Name=MTA-SSL, M=s')dnl
define(`confDEF_CHAR_SET', `iso-8859-1')dnl
define(`confMAX_MESSAGE_SIZE', `15000000')dnl Denial of Service Attacks
define(`confMAX_DAEMON_CHILDREN', `30')dnl Denial of Service Attacks
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `2')dnl Denial of Service Attacks
define(`confMAXRCPTSPERMESSAGE', `50')dnl Denial of service Attacks
define(`confSINGLE_LINE_FROM_HEADER', `True')dnl
define(`confSMTP_LOGIN_MSG', `$j')dnl
define(`confDONT_PROBE_INTERFACES', `True')dnl
define(`confTO_INITIAL', `6m')dnl
define(`confTO_CONNECT', `20s')dnl
define(`confTO_HELO', `5m')dnl
define(`confTO_HOSTSTATUS', `2m')dnl
define(`confTO_DATAINIT', `6m')dnl
define(`confTO_DATABLOCK', `35m')dnl
define(`confTO_DATAFINAL', `35m')dnl
define(`confDIAL_DELAY', `20s')dnl
define(`confNO_RCPT_ACTION', `add-apparently-to')dnl
define(`confALIAS_WAIT', `0')dnl
define(`confMAX_HOP', `35')dnl
define(`confQUEUE_LA', `5')dnl
define(`confREFUSE_LA', `12')dnl
define(`confSEPARATE_PROC', `False')dnl
define(`confCON_EXPENSIVE', `true')dnl
define(`confWORK_RECIPIENT_FACTOR', `1000')dnl
define(`confWORK_TIME_FACTOR', `3000')dnl
define(`confQUEUE_SORT_ORDER', `Time')dnl
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS', `authwarnings,goaway,restrictmailq,restrictqrun,needmailhelo')dnl
FEATURE(`delay_checks')dnl
FEATURE(`generics_entire_domain')dnl
FEATURE(`local_procmail')dnl
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')dnl
FEATURE(`nouucp',`reject')dnl
FEATURE(`redirect')dnl
FEATURE(`relay_entire_domain')dnl
FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl
FEATURE(`virtuser_entire_domain')dnl

FEATURE(dnsbl,`blackholes.mail-abuse.org',
` Mail from $&{client_addr} rejected; see http://mail-abuse.org/cgi-bin/lookup?$& {client_addr}')dnl
FEATURE(dnsbl,`dialups.mail-abuse.org',
` Mail from dial-up rejected; see http://mail-abuse.org/dul/enduser.htm')dnl

FEATURE(`virtusertable',`hash -o /etc/mail/virtusertable')dnl
FEATURE(access_db)dnl
FEATURE(lookupdotdomain)dnl
FEATURE(`blacklist_recipients')dnl
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Name=MTA')dnl
MAILER(local)dnl
MAILER(smtp)dnl
```

Something that's bugging me and I don't know if it's normal, but sendmail doesn't write any messages to /var/log/maillog when I try to authenticate by hand  or when I send mail thru roundcube.  Normal?

**EDIT 2**

I'm generating the auth plain string using:

```
echo -ne "\0user\0password" | base64
```

...then copy & pasting thru telnet

Comment: That is not your SMTP server. Your connection was hijacked by your ISP and diverted to _their_ mail server. Try connecting to your SMTP server from another host on the Internet, _not_ from a residential connection.

Comment: Exactly the same thing happens when I telnet localhost while logged into the box.  Same results when logging in from another VPS

Comment: Really? It sure doesn't look like any mail server you might have installed yourself. So you need to describe in painstaking detail exactly what you installed and how you configured it. Your post should be _long_ and contain every relevant detail, even if you haven't been asked for it.

Comment: One thing we can tell for sure: you shouldn't be using port `25` for authenticated, outbound mail. That will cause problems with most ISPs as they are usually blocking port `25` to any other server than their own SMTP server. Use *submission* on port `587`, instead. Also, please use `STARTTLS` instead of `AUTH PLAIN`.

Comment: The EHLO command is for you to declare your own hostname, not your user name. What you show is NOT how you authenticate to an SMTP server. http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference-auth.htm

Comment: Have you added users to `/etc/mail/virtusertable` which you have defined as the virtual users table?

Comment: @wurtel  Yes.  That table has no passwords.  It maps user@domain.com to user.  If I understand it...